# What makes me die?

Tags: ghost-recon-future-soldier

In Ghost Recon: Future Soldier I've noticed that most of the time that I get shot I'll just fall down, giving my teammates a change to come over and heal me. However, I've also noticed that sometimes I'll just die immediately. What determines which happens? Grenades seem to be very lethal at least.

Answer (score 2):

RPGs and Grenades kill you.

As i noticed: if you get a headshot you die and if you are on the ground enemys will still shoot at you. It is also very possible that you get hit by a burst of bullets and you go to the ground from maybe 3 Bullets but the enemy shot 5 so you still "get hit on the ground" making you die.

Answer (score 2):

If you drop down once and get healed, and get up, it takes time to recharge. If you get immediately shot too much you will die instantly this time, which takes a long time to recharge, maybe up to10 minutes, I don't know exactly. Once you do get up, you have to hug the cover

Answer (score 0):

It depends what difficulty you are playing on.  In my experiences if you are playing on **Elite,** regardless of where you get shot, it can only take 1 to 2 hits before you die.  I've died a few times almost instantly without knowing directly wherefrom (usually from a sniper or in a firefight when things got too hectic).

If you are dying a lot, try changing difficulty up!